# mv command with *-wildcard shows error "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, mv

I have 6 `.txt` files on my desktop that I am trying to move using the Terminal. However when I try to mass move them all into the `texts` folder that is on my Desktop, I get the the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘Desktop/*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Here is the code that I am executing to perform the task:

```
mv Desktop/*.txt Desktop/texts
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Also I am currently in `~/home/dlundy1`

---

Here is out of `ls -al ~/Desktop/*.txt`

```
ls: cannot access /home/ubuntu/Desktop/*.txt: No such file or directory
```

---

** NOTE: ** I want to get the hang of using only the terminal to perform basic tasks to please restrict solutions to those that don't utilize GUI.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add your current working directory (prompt or `pwd` output) and the output of `ls ~/Desktop/*.txt`? Thank you!

Comment: `Desktop/*.txt` is called a "relative pathname", meaning the path is relative to the directory you are currently in. If `Desktop/` is not a child directory of your present working directory, you would need to use an "absolute pathname", such as `/home/user/Desktop/*.txt` or `~/Desktop/*.txt`, where `~` expands to the current users home directory.

Comment: current directory: `~/home/dlundy1`

Comment: I shared a method I used in solving this type of issue at https://askubuntu.com/a/1390049/1566442

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the directory first? If not,

```
mkdir Desktop/texts
```

Use the -p option to create intermediate directories that are missing.

```
mkdir -p Desktop/texts/DoesNotExist/NotHere/Yet
```

You also didn't mention in what path you are currently in, by default the Terminal session starts in your own home directory, but to make sure you could use the full path or the `~` to indicate your home directory. `~` gets expanded to fill out the rest of the path of your home directory.

After making sure the destination exists,

```
mv ~/Desktop/*.txt ~/Desktop/texts
```

Because of the ~, its the same as using,

```
mv /home/dlundy1/Desktop/*.txt /home/dlundy1/Desktop/texts
```

Comment: I did not use this command to create the directory, However I assumed that it exists because I can see it on my desktop.

And I am currently in `home/dlundy1`

Comment: Please then, as ByteCommander asked, edit and post the output of `ls -al ~/Desktop/*.txt`. Also, does the following work command work, `cd ~/Desktop/texts` or does it return an error? If the latter, post the error please.

Comment: post updated with output of `ls -al ~/Desktop/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

When files with names ending in `.txt` exist in the directory `~/Desktop`, the `bash` shell will replace `~/Desktop/*.txt` by the list of files that match the glob pattern `*.txt` before the `mv` command is executed:

```
mv ~/Desktop/*.txt ~/Desktop/texts
```

would be changed to

```
mv ~/Desktop/first.txt ~/Desktop/second.txt ~/Desktop/texts
```

if `~/Desktop` contains `first.txt` and `second.txt`, for example.

But if there are no files matching the glob pattern `*.txt` in `~/Desktop`, the shell has nothing to replace it. Depending on the shell options, it will either refuse to run the command, showing an error, or it will just not change the command, and run it as is. In your case, it did the second: So `mv` tries to move the file with the name `*.txt` in directory `~/Desktop` - but it turns out there is no such file.
The error `cannon stat` means it can not find anything by that name.

So the problem seems to be that the files you like to move do not exist in that directory. Maybe you already moved them?

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following

```
mv ~/Desktop/*.txt ~/Desktop/texts
```

You forgot the **~** which indicates your home directory .

Comment: Depends on the directory he is in! If his working directory (`pwd` output) is already `~/`=`/home/USERNAME/`, the command will also work with just the relative part.

Comment: i assume that he isn't in his home directory because as you can see the error is  ‘Desktop/*.txt’: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, just to make it sure and obvious also for future readers who don't know this.

Comment: I tried this, no luck.

`mv: cannot stat ‘/home/dlundy1/Desktop/*.txt’: No such file or directory`