# cp: cannot stat 'filename': No such file or directory

Tags: command-line

complete noob here, so thanks for your help ahead of time.

A using Linux in my chromebook and trying to intstall Vuescan.

The installation has told me to enter the following:

```
sudo cp vuescan.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

Yet when I do that I get:
cp: cannot stat 'vuescan.svg': No such file or directory

I've searched for hours to try and find a solution but to no avail.
Here's what's in my folders.

---

```
robwilton@penguin:~$ pwd
/home/robwilton
robwilton@penguin:~$ ls

Argyll_V2.1.2
Argyll_V2.1.2_linux_x86_64_bin.tgz
chef
LibreOffice_7.0.1.2_Linux_x86-64_deb
LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
VueScan
vuex6497.tgz

robwilton@penguin:~$
```

---

See attached a screenshot.

[image]

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to `cd` (**c**hange **d**irectory) to the folder that contains the `vuescan.svg` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mv command with \*-wildcard shows error "No such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610202/mv-command-with-wildcard-shows-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @karel I don't think this is the right duplicate, though the issue is similar.

Comment: I searched for something for `No such file or directory` error because he's not in the right directory and that is what I found.

Comment: In the Ubuntu terminal enter the following commands: `pwd`<Enter> and `ls`<Enter>. Then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1293400/edit) and copy and paste the the text from the terminal into the question. Finally format the pasted text as `code` using the { } button above the edit window. The output of these commands will tell us more about your folders, and hopefully how to get to the "My files/Linux files/VueScan" in the terminal. Once you have updated the question, I may be able to provide the exact commands to use to change directory in the terminal.

Comment: If you think so, please accept my answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark  and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved and it may help others.

Comment: thanks user68186, I don't get an error anymore which is promising. But nothing happens, there is no verification that the command was executed. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, normally when a file is successfully copied you don't get a confirmation. Only errors are reported by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with running Ubuntu inside a ChromeOS. It looks to me the folder `VueScan` exists in two places:

1. In the screenshot, the file manager shows the location as: `My files/Linux files/VueScan`
2. Based on the output of the `pwd` and `ls` commands the location is:

   ```
   /home/robwilton/VueScan
   ```

It is possible ChromeOS and Ubuntu denotes the file locations slightly differently. These two are the same location. I will assume that they are.

## Method 1: Change directory and then copy:

### Step 1: Change directory to VueScan in the terminal

Open a terminal (if not already open) and enter:

```
cd VueScan
```

Note, Linux files are case sensitive. `VueScan` and `vuescan` are completely different folders or files. So type with care. When you type the above command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the command prompt will change from:

```
robwilton@penguin:~$
```

to:

```
robwilton@penguin:~/VueScan$
```

Now you know that you are inside the `~/VueScan` folder.

### Step 2: Copy the files as directed:

Now you can follow the instructions and use the `cp` command to copy the files in the location specified. For example:

```
sudo cp vuescan.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

Now the above command should work, and the file `vuescan.svg` resides inside the folder `~/VueScan` and you have entered this folder.

**Note:** Normally when a file is successfully copied you don't get a confirmation. Only errors are reported by default.

## (Advanced) Method 2: Copy with relative or absolute file path

You can avoid the change directory, `cd` command and use just the copy, `cp` command and tell the command where the source file is:

```
sudo cp ~/VueScan/vuescan.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

Note the upper and lower cases in the folder and file names. Also do not forget the `~` and the `/` before the folder name. The `~` stands for your current location, which is `/home/robwilton`. I know this from the `pwd` command output.

So another way of specifying the source file location is:

```
sudo cp /home/robwilton/VueScan/vuescan.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

Now you can copy all the files to their respective location by using one of the two methods.

Hope this helps